# Convert a number in div from number to integer

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have `<div id="mydiv>>111</div>` in html

and I want to get this number by using GetElementbyID(myid).value and convert it to integer

I have tried ParseInt, ParseInt(x, 10), Number(x)....

They all returned NaN. Why?

Note: It works if the number is in a text field, but I want to take it from a div in body.

Comment: Because, well, have you googled on getting html of a div? It should be `innerHTML` for it, not `value` like for `<input>`.

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").value;
```

To :

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML;
```

Example :

```html
<html>
    <head>
       <style>
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mydiv">111</div>
        <script>
            var txt = document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML;
            var num = parseInt(txt);
            alert(num);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```